# Dreaded linker error. Boost and catkin_make

Tags: catkin-make, boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,
I am creating my own package with Boost, and I have a .cpp file that is able to compile using g++ with:

```
g++ newboost.cpp -o boost -lboost_system -lpthread
```

But, when I try to put the .cpp file into my package and catkin_make my package, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/keyencelaser_node.dir/src/newboost.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
keyencelaser/CMakeFiles/keyencelaser_node.dir/build.make:95: recipe for target '/home/ateator/catkin_ws/devel/lib/keyencelaser/keyencelaser_node' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ateator/catkin_ws/devel/lib/keyencelaser/keyencelaser_node] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4463: recipe for target 'keyencelaser/CMakeFiles/keyencelaser_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [keyencelaser/CMakeFiles/keyencelaser_node.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

which is a similar error to the one I got before adding the flags onto the g++ terminal command

I have tried to add Boost into my CMakeLists.txt, but (although it did improve my errors), I am still left with the above errors. My CMakeLists.txt is:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  
)
find_package(
  Boost
  REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread
)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
 add_executable(keyencelaser_node src/newboost.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(keyencelaser_node
   ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARIES}
   ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
 )
```

I am pretty sure it's a linker error but I don't know how to fix it. Again, the edits I made to my CMakeLists.txt eliminated a lot of "undefined reference to" errors, but now that those are gone, I am left with the above. I appreciate any and all help.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250541/dreaded-linker-error.-boost-and-catkin_make/) by [ateator](https://answers.ros.org/users/27086/ateator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2016-12-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ateator](https://answers.ros.org/users/27086/ateator/) on 2016-12-21**:
just tried adding set
(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lboost_system") and
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lpthread") to my CMakeLists, but the error remains the same

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-21**:
Not an answer, but seeing the references to Keyence & lasers: have you seen [ros-industrial/keyence_experimental](https://github.com/ros-industrial/keyence_experimental)? Needs some work, but might be interesting / save you some work.

**Comment by [ateator](https://answers.ros.org/users/27086/ateator/) on 2016-12-21**:
I looked at it, but they use a different laser with a different protocol. That and I have a strong need for the code to be simple (1 file), among more issues. Thank you for checking, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wooow....
So apparently the solution was that I needed to add ${Boost_LIBRARIES} to my target_link_libraries.

---

Originally posted by [ateator](https://answers.ros.org/users/27086/ateator/) with karma: 37 on 2016-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ateator](https://answers.ros.org/users/27086/ateator/) on 2016-12-21**:
note also that I later found that ${catkin_LIBRARIES} was missing from target_link_libraries as well